# GKE Helm http2 connection lost

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

I trying to create a GKE cluster (version: 1.18.15-gke.1500) with a n1-highmem-4 pool.
Everything work fine until I tried to install an helm chart.
The helm binary (version: 3.5.2) end up on the error 'http2 connection lost'.
The GKE trigger an auto-repaire mode.
I don't understand why because I use kubectl to create some configmap without problem.
Did you known if there is some where I can find log about the pool machine or GKE master plan ?

Comment: Hello, could you please tell what exactly are you trying to deploy with `Helm`? Also could you please provide the steps that you are following that your `GKE` cluster is going into the repairing state? As for where you can look for clues, have you checked the `Cloud Operations` logs (formerly `Stackdriver`)?

Answer (score 0):

Without the information on how exactly this cluster was created, what resources were applied with `Helm` and the logs from the cluster (which I will address how to retrieve) it could be hard to pinpoint the issue and a reason behind it.

---

> #### Overview:
>
> GKE's node auto-repair feature helps you keep the [nodes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-architecture#nodes) in your [cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-architecture) in a healthy, running state. When enabled, GKE makes periodic checks on the health state of each node in your cluster. If a node fails consecutive health checks over an extended time period, GKE initiates a repair process for that node.
>
> -- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: How to: Node auto repair: Overview](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-repair#overview)*

Answering the question posted:

> Did you known if there is some where I can find log about the pool machine or GKE master plan ?

Yes. There are ways that you can check your cluster health as well the logs of it.

`GKE` generates a log entry for automated repair events. You can check the logs by using the:

- `gcloud container operations list`

The output should look similar to the one below:

```sh
operation-XXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX  CREATE_CLUSTER     europe-west3-c  example-cluster                                                 DONE    2021-03-07T11:59:55.133563829Z  2021-03-07T12:03:09.684215827Z
operation-YYYYYYYYYYYYY-YYYYYYYY  AUTO_REPAIR_NODES  europe-west3-c  gke-example-cluster-default-pool-AAAAAAAA-AAAA                  DONE    2021-03-07T12:21:14.814774338Z  2021-03-07T12:24:15.6305881Z
```

Adding to that you can look for specific node logs with:  [Google Cloud's operations suite (formerly Stackdriver)](https://cloud.google.com/products/operations)

You can access it by following:

- `GCP Cloud Console (Web UI)` -> `Logging` -> `Upgrade` -> `Upgrade to the New Logs Explorer`

and look for those logs using below filter:

```
resource.type="k8s_node"
resource.labels.cluster_name="CLUSTER-NAME"
resource.labels.project_id="PROJECT-NAME"
resource.labels.location="ZONE"
```

---

Additional resources:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: How to: Node auto repair](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-repair)*
- *[Cloud.google.com: Logging: Docs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs)*